# Accurately detect if a browser supports smooth scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling

Now that Safari 15.4 now supports native smooth scrolling, I am looking for a reliable way to check if a browser uses native smooth scrolling.

I have tried this method:

```
if (getComputedStyle(document.body).scrollBehavior === 'smooth') {
    console.log('Smooth scrolling natively supported ');
}else{
    console.log('Smooth scrolling NOT natively supported');
}
```

But it doesn't accurately detect smooth scrolling on Chrome and Safari 15.4 (it's returning a false negative). This is because `scrollBehavior` is set to `auto`.

I have also tried this method:

```
let supported = 'scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style;
if(supported == true){
    console.log('Smooth scrolling natively supported ');
}else{
    console.log('Smooth scrolling NOT natively supported');
}
```

Which seems to be more reliable, but when I disable smooth scrolling on Google Chrome, it reads a false positive. Could this possibly be because the browser supports it, but it is just not enabled? (I disabled it by starting Chrome from terminal using `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-smooth-scrolling`)

What is the best method for checking is smooth scrolling is natively supported by a browser? Does anyone have an older version (pre v61) that they can test these on or other browsers that don't natively support smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most native way to do this would be to use the `@supports` CSS at-rule to check for browser support:

```css
@supports (scroll-behavior:smooth) {
    /* Supports smooth scrolling */
}
```

To do this check in JavaScript, you may use this function on the CSS object:

```js
if(window.CSS.supports('scroll-behavior', 'smooth')) {
    // Supports smooth scrolling
}
```

Comment: This returns identical results as Method 2 listed in my original post. And I just used Browser Shots to do a lot of testing. This works unless the user specifically disables smooth scrolling.